# Confidence bound of fitted function

Tags: confidence-interval, fitting

I'm dealing with fitting function to data set and with interpretation of such fit and I'm working with Matlab 2011b.

Suppose we have fitted function in form $y=f(a_i,x_j)$ where $a_i$ are parameters and $x_i$ are independent variables and parameters are described by 2-column matrix $A=[a_i;\sigma(a_i)]$ keeping the information of value and confidence interval of each parameter.

I would like to plot the "confidence interval" where the fit should be (with the confidence of 95%) with the fit and original data set.

Example 1:

Data set are points uniformly scattered around central point. Fit is the coordinates of the centre and the "confidence interval" is a sphere around that point with diameter $r=\sigma(x)\equiv\sigma(y)\equiv\sigma(z)$.

Example 2:

Data set is approximated by function $y=ax+0$. The "confidence interval" is area between lines $y=(a-\sigma(a))x$ and $y=(a+\sigma(a))x$.

Example 3:

Data set is approximated by function $y=ax+b$. The "confidence interval" is area between branches of hyperbola-like curve

Comment: Minor question is: Can one suppose that convex hull of all curves with parameters equal to the limits (Example 2 is this case) is the "confidence interval" I am looking for?

Comment: You will need the full variance-covariance matrix of the parameter estimates.  This will ordinarily be supplied by the fitting procedure.

Comment: @whuber Can you, please, expand it a bit more? I have very fair feeling that there are some dark studies called Statistics. Well, seriously, I have very fair knowledge about statistics but maybe I know enough to be very careful and ask twice.

Answer (score 0):

As a part of `curve-fitting toolbox` Matlab already have desired functionality.

Example code:

```
%% define values to be fitted
X=-1:0.1:1;
Y=exp(X)+0.5*(rand(size(X))-0.5);

%% Fit the line expecting function y=a*exp(b*x)
Ff=fit(X,Y,'exp1');

%% Evaluate the fit
x=(-1.1:0.1:1.1)';
y=feval(Ff,x);

%% get 95% confindece bound of function fit
%% (true function lies within the bound with defined probability).
%% for 95% chance that next observation will lie within the bounds use 'observation' parameter
p=predint(Ff,x,0.95,'functional');

%% Plot the data points (dots), fitted curve (solid)
%% and bounds (dotted black line)
plot(X,Y,'.');
hold on
plot(x,y);
plot([x,x],p,'k:');
```